# java: ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() performance

Tags: java, performance, excel, apache-poi

I am writing out a poi workbook to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` in order to get the bytes and send them over in a soap message.

Getting the `ByteArrayOutputStream` is fine, but calling `.toByteArray()` is very slow and uses up a lot of cpu.
The workbook i am trying to convert is very large.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I could speed this up?

Thank you,
Jason

Comment: It's `O(n)` where `n` is the number of bytes written to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: I would expect that converting them to base64 (or whatever) would be rather more expensive than `toByteArray`...

Comment: Are you planning on using the `ByteArrayOutputStream` for anything else? If no, why not write the `byte[]` directly to the SOAP API?

Comment: Consider usage of NIO

Comment: Thank you. The base64 encoding is actually very quick. the toByteArray is a factor 20/30x quicker. I need to get the bytes[] so I can base64 encode it

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Wouldn't it be `O(n^2)` because for each byte it goes through it will call `System.arraycopy(...)`?

Comment: @MohammadS. No, when you a add to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, if there is no room left in the underlying `byte[]`, a new `byte[]` is created with at least twice the size. So this takes `O(k)` whenever capacity is not enough. For just retrieving the `byte[]` at the end, that's `O(n)`, because you're just copying the whole `byte[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you declaring a buffer size when creating the ByteArrayOutputStream object? If not, you're spending the time to expand the buffer and copy over the bytes each time it expands. Set the final size needed in the constructor and you should see some speed improvement for a large file.

From Oracle Documentation:
Constructor and Description

```
ByteArrayOutputStream()
```

Creates a new byte array output stream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream(int size)
```

Creates a new byte array output stream, with a buffer capacity of the specified size, in        bytes.

Comment: No I haven't. Your answer does speed things up by a bit. By a bit I mean from 7minutes to around 5minutes. Is the .toByteArray() operation expected to be intensive?

Comment: This article should shed some light on your question:  http://java-performance.info/java-io-bytearrayoutputstream/

Comment: @JasonTan That's a 28% performance increase, and you asked how to speed it up.

Comment: Using a ByteBuffer instead should speed it up considerably more.

Answer (score 2):

The only intensive task `ByteArrayOutputStream#toByteArray()` is doing is copying bytes from internal stream buffer into new byte array.

I am sure you do not need to do this, because you will send these bytes to SOAP anyway.
You should use `ByteArrayOutputStream#writeTo(OutputStream os)` method instead to write bytes from the byte stream to your SOAP output stream.

Comment: Did you mean `ByteArrayOutputStream#writeTo(OutputStream os)`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider also [Spring Core](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)'s [FastByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FastByteArrayOutputStream.html).

It doesn't copy bytes on growing and also allows to consume them without copy too by means of [toByteArrayUnsafe()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FastByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArrayUnsafe--) and [getInputStream()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FastByteArrayOutputStream.html#getInputStream--) methods.

Note that `toByteArrayUnsafe()` would avoid copying only in case `initialBlockSize` was enough for the whole data.